# MongoDB realtime query

Tags: mongodb, real-time, rethinkdb

I've heard about RethinkDB and since I'm developing a multi-player online game I think if MongoDB **pushes** the changes (let's say new rows) instead of **pulling** rows, it would be much faster for both server-side and client-side.

Is there any wrapper or techniques to make a realtime query to MongoDB or not?

Comment: Jorge @ RethinkDB here. Just out of curiosity, why not just use RethinkDB? It's also a NoSQL document store and you get changefeeds out of the box. I don't mean to be pushy, I'm actually just curious!

Comment: @JorgeSilva Nice to have you here! You know, mongodb has tons of articles, resolved issues and drivers. Also most of NodeJS developers use MongoDB because of the `Mongoose`. To be honest, I think replication and sharding in MongoDB works really better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage [tailable cursors](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/) on [capped collections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/). At the lowest level, that would require writing all changes to the capped collection first, then have them be applied by some kind of worker (an event sourcing pattern). That's a severe change of application architecture, so it's probably not what you want.

A more generic approach is to watch the [oplog](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/), a special capped collection that is used to synchronize master and secondary nodes and that contains *all* operations performed on documents, so no change in application architecture is required.

Still, this is somewhat more low-level than what RethinkDB exposes, in particular because you need to perform a diff. There are [wrappers](https://github.com/cayasso/mongo-oplog) that can hide some of the complexity, but I haven't used them and I don't know what programming language you're using. [Oplog monitoring](http://www.slideshare.net/yaliceme/glasser-devshop10oplog) is [used, for example, by Meteor](http://blog.mongolab.com/2014/07/tutorial-scaling-meteor-with-mongodb-oplog-tailing/), which is pretty much built on publish/subscribe and hides most of the complexity, so it's generally possible, though it seems it's more complicated than with RethinkDB.

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you. One more question, after detecting a change using `tail oplog`, should I make a new query to the `mongo` instance and fetch the records or not?

Comment: hm, now that you say it, that's probably a very easy way to get around the diff problem ;-) I mean, you don't *have* to, because the oplog information is sufficient to advance the document to its current state, but on the other hand, that requires understanding and re-implementing how mongodb applies those operations, which is relatively hard to do. Re-fetching is definitely a lot easier, but will incur more queries, so this is a code-complexity / performance tradeoff. Start with re-querying, if performance is sufficient, you're done, if not reiterate.

Comment: Aha, got it! So, I think this is directly related to performance issues as well.